# MySQL not working on localhost

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp, wampserver

Currently, we are building a project about website blocking and I just have a few questions about php and how phpmyadmin reacts to certain actions. I am using wampserver
signup.php apparently shows no errors when inputting a new account, the username and password is supposed to be saved in the database.
Here it is:

```
<?php 
require_once ("functions.php");
require_once ('config.php');
require_once ('User.php');
require_once ('Session.php');

$default_label = 0;
$error = null;

if($session->isLoggedIn()){
    redirectTo("home.php");
} 

if(requestIsPost()) {
    global $session;
    $params = requiredPostParams(['username' , 'password' , 'label'] , $strict=true);

    if($params != null){
        $default_label = $params['label'];

        // put the data into data base and redirect to login

        $ouser = User::findByUsername($params['username']);

        if($ouser == null) { 

            try{
                $nuser = new User();
                $nuser->initialize($params['username'] , $params['password'] , $params['label']);
                $nuser->save();

                // everything is set, train the recognizer
                $faceLIb = new COM($LIB_CLSID); 
                $nextDir = $unused_face_dir."/s".(string) $default_label;
                $nextDirDest = $face_dir."/s".(string) $default_label;
                rename($nextDir , $nextDirDest);        // move directory into usable faces
                $faceLIb->train($face_dir , $rec_path);

                redirectTo("login.php");
            } catch (InvalidUserData $iud) {
                $error = "Invalid user data. Try Again";
            } catch (DBQueryException $dbe) {
                $error = "Application Error. Try Again";
            } catch (DBConnectException $dce) {
                $error = "Application error. Try Again";
            }
        } else {
            $error = "Email alredy registered";
        }
    }
} 
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Signup</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php if($error != null) echo $error; ?>

 <form action="" method="post" id = "dataform">
  Email: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="label" id = "label" value = <?php echo '"'.$default_label.'"'; ?> >
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_form">
</form> 

<!-- the video scanner -->
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480" style = "display:none"></canvas>

<h1 id="status"></h1>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

// test if the camera is available

var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    });
}

// event handlers
$("#snap").on("click" ,  function(){

    train = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "train.php",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    if(result.code == 1) {
                        $("#label").val(result.label);
                        $("#status").text("Succesful");
                    }       
                    else alert("Face detection Failed! Try again");
                }
        });
    }

    // send an image to the server, on sucess call recursive. do it 'i' times
    send_images = function(i){
        if( i === 0 ) {
            $("#status").text("submitting ...");
            train();
            return;
        }

        $("#status").text(i);

        // extract an image from the live camera
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "upload.php",
            //dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {
                "url" : url
            },
            success: function(result){
                  send_images(i-1);
            }
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ready.php",
            success: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
            }
        });

    send_images(10);
});

$("#submit_form").on("click" , function(){
    var label = parseInt($("#label").val());
    if(label < 1) alert("User saved. Use Snap photo to train image.");
    else $('form#dataform').submit();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>

<?php

require_once("config.php");
require_once("SQLTable.php");
require_once("Validator.php");
require_once("Texter.php");
require_once("exceptions.php");

class User extends SQLTable{
    /**
    * @Overridden properties
    */
    protected static $tableName = 'users';
    protected static $dbFields = array("id" , "name" , "password" , "label");
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @type: SQL.varchar(64)
    * Name of the user, should not contain anything other than alpha and whitespace
    */
    protected $name;            //TODO : TEST what happens while saving if some variable is not set
    /**
    * @type: SQL.varchar(64)
    * Encrypted user password, Real Escaping is done after the encryption
    */
    protected $password;        
    protected $label;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
    * get functions
    */
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLabel(){
        return $this->label;
    }

    /**
    * Sets all the properties of object.
    * Must call this function before calling save on this object, if not initialized by find* functions
    */
    public function initialize($name=null , $password=null , $label= null){
        if(Validator::isValidEmail($name)){
            $this->name = $name;
        }else {
            throw new InvalidUserData("Username is not valid");
        }
        if(Validator::isValidPassword($password)){
            $this->password = Texter::encryptPassword($password);
        }else {
            throw new InvalidUserData("Password is not valid");
        }

        $this->label = $label;
    }

    /**
     * @Defination: Reset saved password 
     * */
    public function setPassword($newPass) {
        if(Validator::isValidPassword($newPass)){
            $this->password = Texter::encryptPassword($newPass);
        }else {
            throw new InvalidUserData("Password is not valid");
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @Defination: Authenticate user by name and password
    * @return: Object of this class if authenticated, null otherwise
    */
    public static function authenticate($name = null , $password = null){
        if(! Validator::isValidEmail($name) || ! Validator::isValidPassword($password)) 
            return null;
        $name = self::escapeValue($name);
        /**TODO, find how right is next step ? */
        $password = Texter::encryptPassword($password);
        $password = self::escapeValue($password);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".static::$tableName;
        $sql .= " WHERE name = '{$name}' AND ";
        $sql .= "password = '{$password}' ";
        $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
        $resultSet = self::findBySQL($sql);
        return !empty($resultSet) ? array_shift($resultSet) : null;
    }   

    public static function findByUsername($name = null){
        if(! Validator::isValidEmail($name)) return null;
        $name = self::escapeValue($name);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".static::$tableName ." WHERE name='{$name}' LIMIT 1";
        $resultSet = self::findBySQL($sql);
        return !empty($resultSet) ? array_shift($resultSet) : null;
    }       
}
```

PS. I might need to upload other codes as well but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Have you looked in the error logs?

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is not the database. MySQL is the database.

Comment: This can be a bigger issue than just PHP not working but making sure that there are no crashed in XAMPP (what I presume you're using) - we need more information :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume it, config.php is your database file. If yes change the order of file to top and then try.